# Pass variable between fragments Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My structure

```
WEB-INF
└── thymeleaf
    ├── fragments
    │   └── head.html
    ├── index
    │   └── index.html
    └── layout.html
```

`layout.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:insert="~{fragments/head :: head}" th:remove="tag"></head>
<body>
    <!--${view} == "index/index"-->
    <div th:insert="~{${view} :: content}" th:remove="tag"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title id="pageTitle">My Title with ID</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="title">My Title With fragment</div>
<div th:fragment="content">
    My page
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`head.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head" th:remove="tag">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>??????</title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to `Spring` and `Thymeleaf`. I'm trying to build a simple CRUD, but I'm stuck in the following situation:

What I want is: in `index.html` set a `title` variable and in `head.html` `fragment` retrieve this `title` variable and print it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 14):

I think you are looking for [8.3 Flexible layouts](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#flexible-layouts-beyond-mere-fragment-insertion) The documentation is awesome and easy to follow, but here is also simple case for just inserting title string

**layouts/layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="page(title)">
    <head th:replace="fragments/head :: common_header(title=${title})"></head>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="this :: content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**fragments/head.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:fragment="common_header(title)">
        <title th:text="${title}">The awesome application</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**index.html** (`indexTitle` comes from controller or you can just put string there)

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:include="layouts/layout :: page(title=${indexTitle})">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section th:fragment="content">
           <div class="block">Part of index.html</div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is also simplified [github demo](https://github.com/varren/ThymeleafLayout) from one of my project you can play with

Comment: Friend. It works like a charm to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use th:include.

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="header :: title">
</head>
<body>
<div>My Title With fragment</div>
<div>
    My page
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> head.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="title" >
    <title>??????</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that th:include is deprecated nowadays, primarily because there's better options such as parameterized fragments.